# Connect Segmentation Fault in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I am getting an error on my connect segmentation fault and program crashes. 
SIGSEGV

```
//notepad.cpp
connect(Properties->UI->okWordPushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(wordcount(int)));

void notepad::wordcount(int wcount)
{

        wcount = ui->textEdit->toPlainText().split(QRegExp("(\\s|\\n|\\r)+"), QString::SkipEmptyParts).count();
        Properties->UI->wordcountlabel->setText(QString::number(wcount))

}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that when I press okWordPushButton in Properties it will read from notepad->textEdit and send an int to Properties->wordcountlabel

```
//notepad.h
public slots:
    void wordcount(int);
```

I have included all the files for properties but I get that error. 
Please help.

Comment: Which line causes the seg-fault?  The call to `connect` or the call to `notepad::wordcount`?

Comment: the connect. I comment out the connect and it runs but does not have functionality of course.

Comment: I believe you can't have a slot receive more arguments than what the signal sends. Try removing `int` inside `SLOT(wordcount(int))`.

Comment: Neven. It does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a different approach.

```
 connect(Properties, SIGNAL(wordComboChanged(int, QString)), this,SLOT(calculateWordCount(int, QString)));
connect(this, SIGNAL(wordCountUpdated(int)), Properties, SLOT(updateWordCount(int)));
```